# Histogram tracking inventory levels in R

Tags: r, histogram

I am looking for a way to visualize inventory throughout a day. The dataset looks as follows, with the summaries of the last two columns below:

```
                 Time  Price Inventory Duration
1 9/1/2016 9:25:06 AM 13.960    318        0
2 9/1/2016 9:36:42 AM 13.980    106      696
3 9/1/2016 9:40:52 AM 13.990   -599      250
4 9/1/2016 9:52:54 AM 14.015     68      722
5 9/1/2016 9:52:54 AM 14.015    321        0
6 9/1/2016 9:54:17 AM 14.010     74       83
```

Inventory

```
 Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-1120.00   -98.75     9.00     0.00   100.00  1988.00
```

Duration

```
Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
 0.00     40.25    205.50   2100.00    529.00 272700.00
```

I want to visualize the data by showing how much time was spent on various inventory levels.  What would you recommend as a function for this? So far I found only histograms based on frequency, not time. My intended result would look similar to this:

*https://postimg.org/image/z074waij1/*

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try with this: `barplot(prop.table(table(df$Inventroy,df$Duration)),beside=T)`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following function for my needs. Hope it helps

```
inv.barplot.IDs <- function(inv.list, IDs = 1:1620)
  {
    # Subset according to the IDs
    myinvs <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 14))
    names(myinvs) <- inv.names
    Volume <- Duration <- vector("numeric")

    for (i in IDs)
    {
      #myinvs <- rbind(myinvs, inv.list[[i]])
      Volume <- c(Volume, as.numeric(inv.list[[i]]$Volume))
      Duration <- c(Duration, as.numeric(inv.list[[i]]$Duration))
    }

    # Design a sequence of skatules
    minimum <- min(Volume)
    maximum <- max(Volume)
    width <- (maximum + abs(minimum)) / 18
    width <- round(width, -1)
    seq.pos <- seq(width, maximum + width, by = width)
    seq.neg <- - seq(0, abs(minimum) + width, by = width)
    seq <- c(rev(seq.neg), seq.pos)

    # Categorize the dataframe (new column)
    Skatule <- numeric(length = length(Volume))
    for (i in 1:length(Volume))
    {
      Skatule[i] <- seq[head(which(seq > Volume[i]), 1) - 1]
    }

    barplot.data <- tapply(Duration, Skatule, sum)

    # Save the barplot
    #jpeg(filename = file.barplot, width = 480 * (16/9))
    inv.barplot <- barplot(barplot.data, border = NA, ylim = c(0, max(barplot.data)), main = "Total time spent on various inventory levels", xlab = "Inventory", ylab = "Log of Hours")
    #print(inv.barplot)
    #dev.off()
  }
```